# A Tic-Tac-Toe variant with three marks - winning strategy and chances

Tags: strategy, game, tic-tac-toe

We start with a usual $3 \times 3$ grid, $3$ different marks (say, $X, O, I$) and $2$ players.

- Player $A$ has to make a vertical, horizontal or diagonal line made of $3$ identical marks (XXX, OOO or III).
- Player $B$ has to make a vertical, horizontal or diagonal line made of $3$ different marks (XOI, OXI, XIO, IOX, IXO or OIX).

If both players have a 'winning' position on the last step, the game is a draw.

Below is an illustration (only some separate examples of winning lines are shown for $A$ and $B$, it's not a full list neither it's an example of a final board).

[image]

> Which player has better chances at winning, if they go first? If the other goes first?
>
> Which player has an easier time forcing a draw in each case?
>
> Are the winning/draw strategies for Players $A$ and $B$ fundamentally different?

Comment: Can they overlap - can they complete an existing row or column with their own character to win?

Comment: @Zxyrra, would it make the game more interesting?

Comment: potentially although it would make it much harder for A

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solution

> The second player always wins.

---

### Step-by-step deduction

**If A plays first**, then

> **B wins**.

Proof: the crucial realisation is that B can *always* force A to play in a specific square. WLOG, say A's first move is an $X$.

- If A's first move is in a corner (WLOG, an $X$), B plays as follows:

  > ```
  > X   O   ?
  >
  > O   .   .
  >
  > ?   .   .
  > ```

  where the ? marks denote the positions of A's subsequent forced moves (each of which can be either an $X$ or an $O$). Finally, B plays

  > an $I$ in the centre to guarantee victory.
- If A's first move is in the middle of an edge (WLOG, an $X$), B plays as follows (first $O$, then $I$):

  > ```
  > I   .   .
  >
  > X   O   ?
  >
  > .   .   .
  > ```

  where the ? mark denotes the position of A's forced move (either an $X$ or an $O$). At this point, A cannot prevent B both from completing the first column and from completing the leading diagonal.
- If A's first move is in the centre (WLOG, an $X$), B plays as follows (first $O$, then $I$):

  > ```
  > I   .   .
  >
  > O   X   ?
  >
  > .   .   .
  > ```

  where the ? mark denotes the position of A's forced move (either an $X$ or an $O$). At this point, A cannot prevent B both from completing the first column and from completing the leading diagonal.

**If B plays first**, then

> **A wins** (thanks @IvoBeckers for help with this part of the proof).

Proof: we can more or less adapt the same proof as used in the first half of the solution.

- If B's first move is in the centre or in the middle of an edge, then A can employ a strategy identical to B's strategy described above, except playing $X$ at every turn instead of $O$ or $I$, thus forcing B's hand in the same way as B forced A's when A went first.
- If B's first move is in a corner (WLOG, an $X$), A plays more $X$'s, first in the centre and then adjacent to the filled corner:

  > ```
  > X   X   .
  >
  > .   X   .
  >
  > .   .   ?
  > ```

  where the ? mark denotes the position of B's forced move (either an $O$ or an $I$). At this point, B cannot prevent A both from completing the first row and from completing the second column.

Comment: I don't get it so far. Why wouldn't A just continue building an X line on his second go? So far B only managed to fill 1 cell, so there are 2 cells available. Then on the next step B makes it impossible to finish the line of course, but A can still try to continue in another cell

Comment: @YuriyS At every stage, A *has* to play so as to block B from completing a row or column. (To address your specific question of why A doesn't play an X, I'll need to know which game/scenario you're talking about.)

Comment: @ randal'thor, you are right, B would just win on their second step in the case I described. Sorry

Comment: To complete your answer: the person that goes second always wins. When B goes first, then for all three examples you have replace all O and I in your examples with X and that's the strategy that player A has

Comment: @Ivo I don't think that always works. For instance, take the first example: B plays $X$ in the corner; A plays $X$'s next to that forcing B to play $O$ and $I$ in the next corners; then A can't play $X$ in the middle!

Comment: yeah you're right, I wasn't thinking haha. i think it does work for the third case but not the first two cases indeed

Comment: solution first two cases: put X in middle first and then for first case in middle left and in second case top left

Comment: @Ivo Actually the second case can be tweaked slightly to be almost identical to the third. So the second and third cases both extend as you say to the case when B plays first.

Comment: @Ivo Sorry, not getting your last comment ...

Comment: First case: player A puts X in middle forcing B to put bottom right. Then A puts X middle left.  
Second case: player A puts X in middle forcing B to put middle right. Then A puts X top left.

Comment: @YuriyS Proof is complete!

Comment: @randal'thor, thank you. I did not expect this result, but it's rather symbolic - second player alwasy wins!